pytorch doesn't read input channels as it's supposed
I'm building a conv3d model for videos using pytorch. the input is (2, 30, 46, 140, 1) but pytorch reads that the input channel is the second one and it's actually the 4th.
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 3, 3, 3], expected input[2, 30, 46, 140, 1] to have 1 channels, but got 30 channels instead

I tried to reshape the input to be (2, 1, 30, 46, 140) but then it doesn't show the frames and gives an error that input is wrong
TypeError: Invalid shape (30, 46, 140) for image data

keep in mind that I tried running the same model with same input on tensorflow and it worked but I can't work with tensorflow due to dependency issues

I solved the problem I transposed the shape in the customdataset class then I re-transposed it to view the frame images
